# Change basic Dijkstra to implement transport routing?

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have implemented Dijkstra to find the shortest path. After the path is found, I need to find out which agencies go through which stops, and then build unique routes for those agencies.

I have the following classes:

```
public class Stop() 
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class Line() 
{
    public int Number {get; set;}
    public int Agency {get; set;}
    public List<LineStop> Stops {get; set;}
}

public class LineStop() 
{
    public Stop Stop {get; set;}
    public int Sequence {get; set;}
}

public class Path() 
{
    public List<Stop> Stops {get; set;}
}
```

`Path` is the shortest path return by the algorithm. `Stop` is a stop on that path. `Line` is a route done by a particular agency. Different agencies can travel the same route or part of the route. Each line is unique. `LineStop` is a list of all the stops for that particular line. It is also possible that 2 different agencies service the exact same line.

After the path is found, a second algorithm should go through the path's stops and build routes based on agencies and their lines.

Currently the search does not need to be time-dependent.

Should such a second algorithm be implemented within Dijkstra or should I keep this second algorithm separate and execute it after the path search?

Any ideas on how this second algorithm might look like?

Comment: I would build another graph where two `Stop`s A-B are connected via an edge iff there is an agency that has a `Line` to connect these points. run dijkstra on the new graph and be done with it

Comment: @Benj Can you elaborate a little bit further? So if my shortest path consists of just 5 stops, should I build a new graph with those 5 stops and create edges based on the agencies stopping at those stops?

Comment: The idea would be to modify your initial graph. I.e. now you have a Graph where Vertices represent cities and Edges represent streets. You construct a new Graph as follows: Vertices represent Cities. Two cities `(V1, V2) in V` `<=>` `'There is an agency that provides a Path from V1 to V2'`. On this (and only this) modified Graph you run Dijkstra. Your `Line` is then a sequence of agencies-`Path`s represented by edges in the modified graph

Comment: @Benj So the edges between (V1, V2) will be weights for different agencies?

Comment: Yes, you weight them by the cost (dollar, time, ...) the agency can provide and your algorithm picks the cheapest (or shortest) edge. I mean, you have to be optimizing by some criteria

Comment: @Benj In the case of this subgraph, there isn't a particular weight for each agency. The `shortest path` should be the path with the least changes between stops. The algorithm should also return all possible shortest paths of this subgraph.

Comment: [1] Ok, then weight each edge in the new graph by the sum of changes between all stops in a path [2] If you need ALL shortest paths, you might consider using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm instead of Dijkstra.